# Supabase.Something went wrong! Unknown error. If this continues please contact support

Tags: supabase

Supabase.Something went wrong! Unknown error. If this continues please contact support.

Why i cant use Logs Explorer, i deploy supabase by Self-Hosting

```
{
  "code": 502,
  "errors": [],
  "message": "Something went wrong! Unknown error. If this continues please contact support.",
  "status": "UNKNOWN"
}
```

and i found error in network
[image]

http://192.168.201.56:8000/api/integrations/default-org-slug?expand=true
http://192.168.201.56:8000/api/projects/default/billing/subscription

They are 404

Comment: Did you set [BigQuery](https://supabase.com/docs/reference/self-hosting-analytics/introduction#docker-image-configuration)?